# How to copy all files and folders of a different azure directory using databricks (without Azure data factory)

Tags: azure, databricks, access-keys

i want to connect to folder in other azure directory from Databricks. I have access keys but it is not working.
What is other way to do it?

```
spark.conf.set( "fs.azure.account.key.<storageAccountName>.dfs.core.windows.net","accessKey")

df=spark.read.csv("abfss://containerName@storageAccountName.dfs.core.windows.net/folder/")
display(df)
```

Error

```
AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.", 401, HEAD, https://<storageAccount>.dfs.core.windows.net/folder/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to add the code that you are using. Is it possible for you to use mount locations? And do the current directory and target directory belong to same storage account?

Comment: Same code works if i use storage account of same directory where we have databricks but i am getting error with different directory

Comment: Is the storage account blob storage or ADLS gen2?

Comment: Is this access key `SAS token`?

Comment: This is access key or Account key

Comment: Reproducing the same is working fine for me. Is it possible for you to set up a service principle and login using OAuth authentication?

Comment: Are you using access key of storage account which is in another directory?

Comment: I have used the access key of storage account. Can you please clarify this: You are trying to move files from one directory to another directory (or is it 2 separate storage accounts)?

Comment: i have 2 azure directory and each has separate storage account, i need to read data from one directory storage account, make some changes and put it into another directory storage account

Comment: i got the solution, bit strange.. Changing cluster worked

Comment: consider posting it as answer so it might help other community members facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing cluster make same code worked.
Not sure of the reason though